# OS-X Bluetooth stack

Tags: macos, bluetooth, osx-yosemite, hid

**Use-case:** Simulate a Bluetooth HID Keyboard using OS-X Desktop

To be able to simulate HID keyboards over Bluetooth the following is needed:

- HCI level control of the machine COD (**C**lass **o**f **d**evice) major and minor class/service IDs
- L2CAP level control of HID connections consisting of PSMs 0x11 & 0x13 (Interrupt & Control)
- OS-X SDP Definition/Modification

Using linux the above mentioned use-case is supported using the BluZ stack, does the same is supported by the Bluetooth stack provided by **OS-X Yosemite** ?